# Bootstrap display of Form

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-4

This is not making sense to me.  I am trying to display a form on my MVC5 project  with 4 input fields.  When i am not using the @using (HTML.BeginForm(...){..}

> @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "HR", FormMethod.Post))
>   {

my display looks perfect [image]

but once i put in the @using (HTML.BeginForm(..) statement, then the display looks like this:
[image]

Where am I going wrong in my html helper ?

Here are some sample html helper methods i am using..

```
<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h4>Create New Employee</h4></div>
    <div class="panel-body"> 
        <form class="form-horizontal">
     <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter First Name" })
                    </div>
             </div>
     <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Middle Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MiddleName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Middle Name" })
                    </div>
             </div>
     </form> 
  </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean `Html.BeginForm()` in additional to  `<form class="form-horizontal">` (which would be invalid html) or instead of `<form class="form-horizontal">`?

Comment: Yes, If i removed the <form class="form-horizontal">, and just had the Html.BeginForm(),  the display is same as image 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are losing your class attribute when using `@Html.BeginForm`. Add it back like so:

```
<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h4>Create New Employee</h4></div>
    <div class="panel-body"> 
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="form-horizontal" }))
    {
     <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter First Name" })
                    </div>
             </div>
     <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Middle Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MiddleName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Middle Name" })
                    </div>
             </div>
     }
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, it worked as soon as i added the attribute back in the '@using' statement.  I was going crazy. Thanks again.